# Executing machine code in an array in C. Is this executing an Integer?

Tags: c, security, shellcode

I am trying to understand why `ret();` works in the following C program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

unsigned char code[] = \
"\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69"
"\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80";

main()
{
    printf("Shellcode Length:  %d\n", strlen(code));
    int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;
    ret();
}
```

In order for this to work you must compile the above with no stack protections, allowing the stack to be executable.

What I'm wondering though is *why* calling `ret();`, which appears to be an integer assigned to the value `(int(*)())code;` works.

I am guessing it has something to do with function pointers really being integers, but I have not been able to mentally unpack the meaning of the expression `int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;`

Thank you for your help

Comment: [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/?q=%28int%28*%29%28%29%29code%3B) can help with translating C into English

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What I'm wondering though is why calling `ret()`, which appears to be an integer assigned to the value `(int(*)())code` works

`ret` is not an integer, it is a pointer to a function returning an integer. The "inline" syntax, i.e. `int (*ret)()` is harder to "decipher" than an equivalent `typedef`, i.e.

```
typedef int (*func_returning_int)();
...
func_returning_int ret = (func_returning_int)code;
```

**Note:** It goes without saying that this is undefined behavior regardless of the way you go about casting pointers.

Comment: Ok, slowly unpacking this here...

So the left side: `int (*ret)()` is declaring the `ret` function pointer, pointing to a function that takes no arguments (`()`) and the function pointed to returns an int.
    
I'm still confused on what the right side is doing, specifically: `int(*)()`
It looks like that is casting our `unsigned char code[]` array into the type `int(*)()`? Is `int(*)()` just another function pointer, but with no name next to `*`?

Comment: @gatorface That's exactly right, `int(*)()` is the same as `int(*ret)()`, with `ret` omitted.

Answer (score 2):

The cast turns the array, `code` into a pointer to a function and assigns it to the function pointer `ret`.  Since `ret` is a pointer to a function, when you call the function pointed to what happens is that the machine code in the array `code` is executed.

That is the theory. Not sure what the actual machine code that has been stored into the array `code` is.

So `ret` is a pointer to a function that returns an `int`.

Function pointers are not `int` but are instead function pointers.

**Function Pointer Definitions and Declarations**

For a variable definitions such as `int (*ret)()` you have to parse the definition by starting with the variable name, `ret` in this case. What makes function pointer variable definitions more difficult to decipher is that parenthesis are used to define the order of how the expression is parsed and parenthesis are also used as special symbol to indicate that the variable is a function pointer.

A standard function declaration looks like `int retFunc ();` which declares a function that returns an `int`. No arguments are specified in this old style of function declaration so we don't know if there are no arguments or several or their types, if there are arguments. By the way a standard integer variable declaration looks like `int intVar;`.

To create a function pointer variable you need to specify the same information for the function pointer as you do for a function declaration with one additional piece of information, the indication that this is a declaration or definition of a function pointer and not the declaration of a function.

Here is a bit of code with variations of syntax to show the differences between the declaration of a function and the declaration of a function pointer.

```
main () {
    extern int retFunc();    // declaration of a function, returns int
    extern int (*ret)();     // declaration of a function pointer, function returns int
    extern int *retFunc2();  // declaration of a function, returns int pointer
    extern int *(*retVar)(); // declaration of a function pointer, function returns a pointer to an int
    extern int (*((*ret2)()))(); // declaration of a function pointer, function returns a function pointer which points to a function that returns an int
}
```

What differentiates these five is the use of the pointer indicator in the second, fourth, and fifth declarations with parenthesis to enforce how the compiler is to interpret the declaration. The grouping parenthesis are needed due to the operator precedence rules which causes the compiler to place higher precedence on the parenthesis indicating a function so we override the precedence rules by using grouping parenthesis.

The fifth one is especially interesting, `extern int (*((*ret2)()))();` which can be parsed out in two stages. The first is the piece `((*ret2)()))` which indicates the symbol `ret2` is a pointer to a function and the second stage is to determine the return type of the function pointed to, a pointer to a function that returns an `int` by replacing the first piece with an arbitrary symbol *x* as in `int (*x)();`.

When creating a function pointer declaration we must be aware of operator precedence rules of C and how these may affect how the compiler interprets a declaration or a definition. We need to add the additional parenthesis around the `*ret` in the function pointer declaration so that the compiler sees this as a pointer to a function that returns an `int` rather than a function that returns a pointer to an `int`.

The rules the C compiler uses sometimes requires that parenthesis be used to enforce an order of translation of an expression in order for the expression to have the desired meaning. And those rules sometimes result in the same character or symbol to have different meanings in different contexts. So `int ret();` the parenthesis makes the symbol `ret` to be a function and `int (ret);` the parenthesis are used to group symbols, in this case just a single symbol and `int (*ret)();` parenthesis are used to both group symbols and to indicate a function, in this case that `ret` is a pointer to a function.

In your example rather than a declaration of a variable `ret` as a function pointer you are defining the variable and assigning it a value in the statement `int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;`. The rules for parsing a definition are similar to the rules for parsing a declaration.

In your example `code` is defined as an array of `unsigned char` with what I assume is machine code specified in the initialization of the array.

In C an array variable can be considered a constant pointer variable in many ways. So you can dereference an array name which means that `code[1]` is the same as `*(code + 1)` however since it is a constant pointer you can not do something like `code = code + 1;` though you could do something like `unsigned char *code1 = (code + 1);` which is the same as `unsigned char *code1 = &code[1];`.

So in the statement `int (*ret)() = (int (*)())code;` you are casting the constant pointer `code` which points to an `unsigned char` to a function pointer to a function that returns an `int`. As long as there is some way to go from the type on the right hand side of the assignment operator to the type on the left hand side of the assignment operator, the C compiler is happy to oblige what ever fantasies you want to create.

However just because the compiler is happy to generate machine code from an expression does not mean that the underlying operating system and hardware will be happy with the result when the program is actually run. These gray areas, areas of undefined behavior, may result in a program that runs sometimes and not other times or may run in one environment but not another.

The cast of the array `code` makes this a bit more difficult to understand because the syntax of the cast to a function pointer that returns an `int` is similar to the syntax for declaring or defining a function pointer that returns an `int` except that there is no variable after the asterisk in the cast `(int(*)())`. So all those parenthesis can make it a bit confusing.

In the case of this cast, we are using parenthesis to group the complete type cast, `(int(*)())` as well as parenthesis to enforce an order, `(*)`, and parenthesis to indicate that this is a function, `()`. So there are a lot of parenthesis flying about in this type cast.

When it gets more complicated is something like `int *((*ret)()) = (int *((*)()))code;` which is a function pointer to a function that returns a pointer to an `int`.

In cases like this I really prefer to explicitly use parenthesis to specify the order of interpretation rather than relying on my memory of order operator precedence.